# Which UI element for day-switching bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, uitoolbar

In the Calendar app on the iPhone, when displaying a day, you can switch to the next an previous day with a gray bar at the top.

My question is: which interface element would you use for that? UIToolbar, UITabbar or a UINavigationBar?

UINavigationBar provides pretty much what I need: the possibility to add a button at the left and at the right of the bar, plus a label in the middle. But actually, I don't really have a navigation hierarchy.

UIToolbar is, according to Apple's HIG, supposed to sit at the bottom of the screen. I wouldn't really mind if not for the fact that it has no border at the bottom and a small border at the top which makes the whole thing look pretty weird if placed at the top of the screen.

I haven't yet tried UITabbar, because it is intended for something very different from what I need.

Currently, I tend towards UINavigationBar, but the right way to do this is probably to roll my own UI element for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI element in the calendar app is none of those.  It is a UIView with two UIButton subviews and one or two UILabels for the day and date text.  Apple may have written a custom UIView class and a custom UIViewController, but with something as simple as this, it's probably just a custom UIViewController that programmatically builds the view.

You're instincts on this are correct: the right way to do this is to roll your own.